# Git: forcing `add` when file is in nested git repository

Tags: git

I would like to add a file contained into a nested git repository in the parent repository (I'm developing a library that I use in my project). However `git add nested_repo/myfile` does not do anything... I could try to rename the `.git` file when doing the commits, but then I'm afraid to have strange conflicts when I rename back the `.git` folder.

I know submodules is the proper way to handle nested git repositories. Unfortunately in my case I'm using git in conjunction with Overleaf (to share LaTeX documents with co-authors and edit them collaboratively in real-time) and overleaf does not handle submodules (if I try to push a project with submodules it just fails).

Any idea how I could deal with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *right* answer is "don't do that".

> I could try to rename the .git file when doing the commits ...

This does work:

```
mkdir test-subdirectory
cd test-subdirectory
git init
[... output, make initial commit, etc, here]
mkdir sub && (cd sub && git init && echo echo submodule > README &&
git add README && git commit -m initial-in-sub)
[output snipped]
```

At this point, creating `sub/file` and trying to `git add` it does nothing, at least in the version of Git I'm using here (a year or so out of date):

```
git add sub/file
```

There is no error but `sub/file` is not added (nor is `sub` added as a submodule).  But:

```
mv sub/.git sub/notgit
git add sub/file
mv sub/notgit sub/.git
```

Adding a `.gitignore` for `sub`, and `git add .gitignore`, and `git status --short` now says:

```
A  .gitignore
A  sub/file
```

> but then I'm afraid to have strange conflicts when I rename back the .git folder.

It's not so much "strange conflicts", but rather the fact that the top level repository, that now contains `sub/file` where `sub/.git` exists and is a repository, now believes it has the right to create and, if necessary, destroy the directory `sub` and/or its contents.  And indeed it does just that:

```
$ git commit -m 'add sub/file'
[master d6c0cb6] add sub/file
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 sub/file
$ git clean -dfx
Removing sub/README
```

This happens despite `sub/README` being a Git-controlled file in the `sub` Git repository:

```
$ (cd sub; git status --short)
$ (cd sub;git status --short)
 D README
?? file
```

This situation is, in a word, fraught.  Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing problems about cleaning. Except for cleaning, does this method presents other issues?

Comment: It's not *supported*, i.e., if Git wrecks all your files and you gripe to the Git folks they'll just say "don't do that". Future versions of Git might wreck all your files. (If you don't have the nested repositories, of course, it's fine.)

Comment: Yes sure, it's something that I would do at my own risks ^^ But in any case there is no great solution. And in case I want to try (I'll just use hard links in my case so it won't be my situation) it's good to know if it breaks already today or if it's just that it might break things in future updates of git. To be honest, I'm not really surprised that cleaning removes these files as we basically asked git not to consider it as a git repository. So I would not consider it as a "bug", but more as something to know. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: It used to be the case that `git add -f sub/file` would work, but that seems to have been disabled. Presumably between 2.25 and 2.34, given it worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 (which has git 2.25) and no longer works on Ubuntu 22.04 (which has 2.34).

Comment: Narrowed it down, this worked in 2.26.3, and didn't work in 2.27.0. The release notes for 2.27.0 mention "Fix "git checkout --recurse-submodules" of a nested submodule hierarchy.", maybe that's related?!?

Comment: Well, whatever the origin of the change in behavior, using `git update-index --add sub/file` does work in recent git versions, and once you've done that once for one file, git will ignore the fact that the subdirectory is a git repository going forwards.

Comment: @MarkRaymond: Update-index is "plumbing", meaning it (in this case probably deliberately) doesn't check for setting up a potentially-dangerous situation. There's some risk here that Git might remove the subdirectory entirely later. If you're using "absorbed" submodules (where the *repository itself* has been relocated out of the subdirectory), this becomes safe (for some value of "safe"). I expect Git will support non-absorbed subdirectories for a few more years at least though, so there will probably be some double-checking ... until someday there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the file using the low-level plumbing command:

```
git update-index --add nested_repo/myfile
```

then git will treat that file, and all other files in `nested_repo`, normally from then onwards. I.E. once the parent repository is tracking the file, `git add` will work normally to add future changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a solution, but it's what I end-up doing: since I have very few files to manage (actually... only one) I did a hard link of that file (symlink would not work as they are not handled the way I want) to another file in my project. I slightly modified the code to include this new file instead.

Seems to work fine so far. But keep in mind that hard link may vanish if you copy your folders somewhere else, and that it is not supported on all filesystems (e.g. FAT32).