# Nested independent repositories

Tags: git

I'd suspect this question was asked regularly on different corners of internet. But I didn't come across a viable answer.

Imagine the following:

- there is a repository X. Containing folders A, B and C.
- repo X has a remote, let's call it RemoteX.
- inside folder B, there is an independent repository Y.
- repo Y has it's own remote called RemoteY.
- all job is done in regular way in repository X. With branching and everything
- once in a while, snapshots pushed from folder B to repo Y. "Backups" in a way.
- repo Y has only 1 branch. There is no development done in it. It exists purely as separate version controlled cloud-based storage repo.
- remote X should contain ALL the contents of all folders (except .git folders of folder B)

How to implement this? I'm 90% sure submodules/subtrees are not the way to go.

I already tried adding B/.git to gitignore of repo X. Didn't help.

UPD:
Here is some visualisation to be more precise

```
Repo X ---> Remote X (Server X)
|
|
.git
|
A
|
B ---> Repo Y ---> Remote Y (Server Y) 
|      |
|      .git
|
C
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?  Did Git give you some error message due to Y existing inside X?  Did Git operations on Y fail?

Comment: Your explanation is too abstract for me to follow, but *maybe* submodules can help achieve what you want?

Comment: @JohnZwinck git refused to add contents of the folder B.

Comment: @JoachimSauer repo X and repo Y are on separate servers. And I want contents of folder B included into repo X, not linked. How can I achieve that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289416/git-forcing-add-when-file-is-in-nested-git-repository - the answer from Mark Raymond may solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you need to nest them? If they are independent, can't they be in separate folders?

Comment: @knittl Repo X should include all the contents of repo Y

Answer (score 0):

### consider [git-subrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo)

It handles your scenario, though under the covers it does one thing differently. Instead of having a a redundant repo Y `.git` directory (since all of that history already exists in repo X's `.git` dir, it has a `.gitrepo` file in repo Y's root. This file only contains metadata about the subrepo (e.g. its remote, sync status with remote, etc).

The nice thing about it is that repo X will look EXACTLY the same as if the Y folder was just like a regular folder.

If Y already exists, here is the command to initialize it as a subrepo:

> ```
> git subrepo init <subdir> [-r <remote>] [-b <branch>] [--method <merge|rebase>]
> ```
>
> Turn an existing subdirectory into a subrepo.
>
> If you want to expose a subdirectory of your project as a published subrepo, this command will do that. It will split out the content of a normal subdirectory into a branch and start tracking it as a subrepo. Afterwards your original repo will look exactly the same except that there will be a `<<subdir`/.gitrepo >> file.
>
> If you specify the `--remote` (and optionally the `--branch`) option, the values will be added to the `<subdir>/.gitrepo` file. The `--remote` option is the upstream URL, and the `--branch` option is the upstream branch to push to. These values will be needed to do a `git subrepo push` command, but they can be provided later on the `push` command (and saved to `<<subdir`/.gitrepo >> if you also specify the `--update` option).
>
> Note: You will need to create the empty upstream repo and push to it on your own, using `git subrepo push <subdir>`.
>
> The `--method` option will decide how the join process between branches are performed. The default option is merge.
>
> The `init` command accepts the `--branch=` and `--remote=` options.